# Wordpress get attachment issue

Tags: wordpress

I am trying to get media attached to the post in WP like this¨

```
if (have_posts()) : while (have_posts()) : the_post(); ?>
    $images = get_attached_media('image');
```

What I have observed is that when creating/editing post if I upload a new image then it gets attached with the post and I get it, but if I use an already uploaded image in the post I don't get that media. Am I missing something here?

Answer (score 1):

you can try with this function.

```
  $attch_id = get_post_thumbnail_id( $post->ID );
  $url = wp_get_attachment_image_src($attch_id);
  echo "<img src='".$url[0]."' />";
```

I hope is useful.